# I cannot install Yaourt: I do not have write permission for the directory

Tags: arch-linux, chrome, manjaro, yaourt, aur

These are the instructions (https://manjaro.site/how-to-install-yaourt-on-arch-linux/) to install Yaourt:

```
git clone https://aur.archlinux.org/package-query.git 
cd package-query 
makepkg -si 
cd .. 
git clone https://aur.archlinux.org/yaourt.git 
cd yaourt 
makepkg -si
```

I successfully run the first two lines, but when running `makepkg` I get the error:

```
=> ERROR: You do not have write permission for the directory $BUILDDIR (/home/pietrom/package-query).
    Aborting...
```

I try with:

```
sudo makepkg -si
```

and I get this error:

```
==> ERROR: Running makepkg as root is not allowed as it can cause permanent, 
catastrophic damage to your system.
```

I change the file's owner:

```
sudo chown pietrom ./PKGBUILD
sudo chgrp users ./PKGBUILD
```

and, again, I get:

```
makepkg -si
==> ERROR: You do not have write permission for the directory $BUILDDIR (/home/pietrom/package-query).
Aborting...
```

What am I doing wrong?

I havo to install Yaourt to install Google Chrome.

Comment: Yaourt is discontinued. Use `yay`. More here https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AUR_helpers

Comment: OK, I installed `yay`, and can use it through Octopi. If you rewrite it as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are not typing `sudo` in front, like this:

`sudo git clone https://aur.archlinux.org/yaourt.git`

Instead, type:

`git clone https://aur.archlinux.org/yaourt.git`